# I can't manage to make this MySQL procedure work like I want it to (Syntax Error)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a simple database for a hotel. It is supposed to take care of all bookings. I am trying to make a procedure which will search for not booked rooms in given date. However, I can't either get any "perfect idea" or even complete the one I have.

I already have a working database filled with data, however it has no procedures. I tried to make a Procedure which will use LOOPs and IFs to do it, but with no success. Later I was told it is a stupid idea.

Can anyone give me any ideas what is wrong or even better, how to make the whole procedure work?

Here is a photo of given tables

[image]

```sql
DELIMITER //

/*Here I intake in order: How many people want to book a room, arrival date, departure date*/
CREATE PROCEDURE wolnePokoje(IN ilosc int, IN poczatek date, IN koniec date)
BEGIN

/*Here I select room Numbers and how many people the room can accommodate*/
SELECT Pokoj.RoomID, Pokoj.IloscMiejsc

/*There is an inner join (INNER may not be correct) of ROOMS and BOOKINGS. */
FROM Pokoj INNER JOIN Rezerwacje ON Pokoj.BookID = Rezerwcje.BookID

/*This WHERE tell me if a Room is booked. (WHERE NOT may not be correct, just like the whole WHERE)*/
WHERE NOT((poczatek < Rezerwacje.DataPrzyjazdu AND poczatek > Rezerwacje.DataOdjazdu) OR ((koniec < Rezerwacje.DataPrzyjazdu) AND (koniec > Rezerwacje.DataOdjazdu))

/*This WHERE I check if a room can accommodate given number of people, it's like "AND number <= numberRoomCanAccommodate"*/
AND ilosc <= Pokoj.IloscMiejsc;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you. Just a side note here: It is easier to communcate with other programmers (outside Poland) if your code is in English. `freeRooms()` is easier to understand than `wolnePokoje()` for 99,8% of the world population. And personally I also think it reads a bit easier if everything is in one language. Of course, the output to the user can be in any language. I'm not a native English speaker myself, so I'm allowed to say this. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a comment not properly closed  and a missing ) for close the NOT clause

```
SELECT Pokoj.RoomID, Pokoj.IloscMiejsc

/*There is an inner join (INNER may not be correct) of ROOMS and BOOKINGS. */
FROM Pokoj INNER JOIN Rezerwacje ON Pokoj.BookID = Rezerwcje.BookID

/*This WHERE tell me if a Room is booked. (WHERE NOT may not be correct, just like the whole WHERE)*/
WHERE NOT((poczatek < Rezerwacje.DataPrzyjazdu AND poczatek > Rezerwacje.DataOdjazdu) 
  OR ((koniec < Rezerwacje.DataPrzyjazdu) AND (koniec > Rezerwacje.DataOdjazdu)))   
                                                                               ^here
```